# What are missing attributes as defined in the hdf5 specification and metadata in group h5md?

Tags: metadata, hdf5, h5py

I have a one hdf5 format file [Data File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/emk2mn6rihtd4iv/xaa.h5?dl=0) containing the molecular dynamics simulation data. For quick inspection, the h5ls tool is handy. For example:

```
h5ls -d xaa.h5/particles/lipids/positions/time | less
```

now my question is based on the comment I received on the data format! What attributes are missing according the hdf5 specifications and metadata in group?

Comment: What do you mean by "_What attributes are missing_"? What error are you getting? Please add to your post. If you aren't getting an error please describe the problem of the "missing attributes". Users do not have to manually create any attributes. HDF5 is a container not a "format". Data organization into groups, datasets and attributes is arbitrary (aka the "schema"). You need to understand HDF5 concepts to work with it. Read [The HDF Group docs here](https://portal.hdfgroup.org/display/HDF5/Learning+HDF5)  Start with **Introduction to HDF5**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to get the value of the Time attribute from a dataset? If so, you need to use `h5dump`, not `h5ls`. And, the attributes are attached to each dataset, so you have to include the dataset name on the path. Finally, attribute names are case sensitive; `Time != time`. Here is the required command for `dataset_0000` (repeat for 0001 thru 0074):

```
h5dump -d /particles/lipids/positions/dataset_0000/Time xaa.h5
```

You can also get attributes with Python code. Simple example below:

```
import h5py 
with h5py.File('xaa.h5','r') as h5f:
    for ds, h5obj in h5f['/particles/lipids/positions'].items():
        print(f'For dataset={ds}; Time={h5obj.attrs["Time"]}')
```

Comment: I guess I defined my problem here more clearly **[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69242841/how-to-create-attributes-to-the-groups-and-access-them-in-hdf5-file-system]**