# How to split the data among the multiple groups in hdf5 file?

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py, hdf

I have one some data which looks something like this:

```
Generated by trjconv : P/L=1/400 t=   0.00000
11214
    1P1     aP1    1  80.48  35.36   4.25
    2P1     aP1    2  37.45   3.92   3.96
11210LI     aLI11210  61.61  19.15   3.25
11211LI     aLI11211  69.99  64.64   3.17
11212LI     aLI11212  70.73  11.64   3.38
11213LI     aLI11213  62.67  16.16   3.44
11214LI     aLI11214   3.22   9.76   3.39
  61.42836  61.42836   8.47704
```

I have managed to write the data in the required groups, except the last line. I want to write this line to a group /particles/box. This specific line repeated in every frame as you can see in the data file [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/np4zddobttbtjq0/com?dl=0). So far the code have been designed in this ways that it somehow ignores this line. I tried some ways but getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Shape tuple is incompatible with data
```

The last line is time dependent i.e., with every time frame it fluctuates a bit I want this data to be linked with step and time datasets which are defined already in the /particles/lipids/positions/step. Here is the code:

```py
import struct
import numpy as np
import h5py
import re

# First part generate convert the .gro -> .h5 .
csv_file = 'com'

fmtstring = '7s 8s 5s 7s 7s 7s'
fieldstruct = struct.Struct(fmtstring)
parse = fieldstruct.unpack_from

# Format for footer
fmtstring1 = '1s 1s 5s 7s 7s 7s'
fieldstruct1 = struct.Struct(fmtstring1)
parse1 = fieldstruct1.unpack_from

with open(csv_file, 'r') as f, \
    h5py.File('xaa_trial.h5', 'w') as hdf:
    # open group for position data
    ## Particles group with the attributes
    particles_grp = hdf.require_group('particles/lipids/positions')
    box_grp = particles_grp.create_group('box')
    dim_grp = box_grp.create_group('dimension')
    dim_grp.attrs['dimension'] = 3
    bound_grp = box_grp.create_group('boundary')
    bound_grp.attrs['boundary'] = ['periodic', 'periodic', 'periodic']
    edge_grp = box_grp.create_group('edges')
    edge_ds_time = edge_grp.create_dataset('time', dtype='f', shape=(0,), maxshape=(None,), compression='gzip', shuffle=True)
    edge_ds_step = edge_grp.create_dataset('step', dtype=np.uint64, shape=(0,), maxshape=(None,), compression='gzip', shuffle=True)
    edge_ds_value = None
    ## H5MD group with the attributes
    #hdf.attrs['version'] = 1.0 # global attribute
    h5md_grp = hdf.require_group('h5md/version/author/creator')
    h5md_grp.attrs['version'] = 1.0
    h5md_grp.attrs['author'] = 'rohit'
    h5md_grp.attrs['creator'] = 'known'
    
    # datasets with known sizes
    ds_time = particles_grp.create_dataset('time', dtype="f", shape=(0,), maxshape=(None,), compression='gzip', shuffle=True)
    ds_step = particles_grp.create_dataset('step', dtype=np.uint64, shape=(0,), maxshape=(None,), compression='gzip', shuffle=True)
    ds_value = None

    step = 0
    while True:
        header = f.readline()
        m = re.search("t= *(.*)$", header)
        if m:
            time = float(m.group(1))
        else:
            print("End Of File")
            break

        # get number of data rows, i.e., number of particles
        nparticles = int(f.readline())
        # read data lines and store in array
        arr = np.empty(shape=(nparticles, 3), dtype=np.float32)
        for row in range(nparticles):
            fields = parse( f.readline().encode('utf-8') )
            arr[row] = np.array((float(fields[3]), float(fields[4]), float(fields[5])))

        if nparticles > 0:
            # create a resizable dataset upon the first iteration
            if not ds_value:
                ds_value = particles_grp.create_dataset('value', dtype=np.float32,
                                                        shape=(0, nparticles, 3), maxshape=(None, nparticles, 3),
                                                        chunks=(1, nparticles, 3), compression='gzip', shuffle=True)
                #edge_data = bound_grp.create_dataset('box_size', dtype=np.float32, shape=(0, nparticles, 3), maxshape=(None, nparticles, 3), compression='gzip', shuffle=True)
            # append this sample to the datasets
            ds_time.resize(step + 1, axis=0)
            ds_step.resize(step + 1, axis=0)
            ds_value.resize(step + 1, axis=0)
            ds_time[step] = time
            ds_step[step] = step
            ds_value[step] = arr
  
        footer = parse1( f.readline().encode('utf-8') )
        dat = np.array(footer)
        print(dat)
        arr1 = np.empty(shape=(1, 3), dtype=np.float32)
        edge_data = bound_grp.create_dataset('box_size', data=dat, dtype=np.float32, compression='gzip', shuffle=True)
        
        step += 1
        #=============================================================================
```

Comment: The line isn't skipped. It's read as `footer` here: `footer = parse1( f.readline().encode('utf-8') )` then used to create array `dat`. Maybe you want to reference it in dataset `boxsize` by setting parameter `data=dat`?

Comment: @kcw78 I tried that as well but but still getting the error **ValueError: Shape tuple is incompatible with data**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a number of small errors when reading and converting the "footer" line.
I modified the code and got it working....but not sure if it does exactly what you want. I used the same group and dataset definitions. So, the footer data is written to this data set:

```
/particles/lipids/positions/box/boundary/box_size
```

That comes from the following group and dataset definitions:

```
particles_grp = hdf.require_group('particles/lipids/positions')
box_grp = particles_grp.create_group('box')
bound_grp = box_grp.create_group('boundary')
edge_data = bound_grp.create_dataset('box_size'....
```

Corrections are required in several places:
First, you need to change the definition of `parse1` to match the 3 fields.

```
# Format for footer
# FROM:
fmtstring1 = '1s 1s 5s 7s 7s 7s'
# TO:
fmtstring1 = '10s 10s 10s'
```

Next, you need to modify where and how the `box_size` dataset is created. You need to create it like the others: as an extensible dataset (`maxshape=()` parameter) ABOVE `while True:` loop. This is what I did:

```
edge_ds_step = edge_grp.create_dataset('step', dtype=np.uint64, shape=(0,), maxshape=(None,), compression='gzip', shuffle=True)
# Create empty 'box_size' dataset here
edge_data = bound_grp.create_dataset('box_size', dtype=np.float32, shape=(0,3), maxshape=(None,3), compression='gzip', shuffle=True)
```

Finally, here is the modified code to:

1. Parse the `footer` string to a tuple,
2. Map the tuple to an np.array of floats, shape=(1,3),
3. Resize the dataset and finally
4. Load the array into the dataset.

   ```
   footer = parse1( f.readline().encode('utf-8') )
   dat = np.array(footer).astype(float).reshape(1,3)
   new_size = edge_data.shape[0]+1
   edge_data.resize(new_size, axis=0)
   edge_data[new_size-1:new_size,:] = dat
   ```