# How to read chunk of the data from a hdf5 file in c++?

Tags: c++11, boost, hdf5

I want to read a chunk of data which is just one frame of many frames stored in one dataset. The shape of the whole dataset is (10, 11214,3), 10 frames each frame has 11214 rows and 4 columns. Here is the [file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/irfy9o7fzvvaymv/xaa.h5?dl=0). The chunk I want to read would have the shape (11214,3). I can print the predefined array using,  but I'm not sure how can I read data from a hdf5 file. Here is my code,

```cpp
#include <h5xx/h5xx.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_array.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>

typedef boost::multi_array<int, 2> array_2d_t;

const int NI=10;
const int NJ=NI;

void print_array(array_2d_t const& array)
{
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < array.shape()[1]; j++)
    {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < array.shape()[0]; i++)
        {
            printf("%2d ", array[j][i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
void write_int_data(std::string const& filename, array_2d_t const& array)
{
    h5xx::file file(filename, h5xx::file::trunc);
    std::string name;

    {
        // --- create dataset and fill it with the default array data (positive values)
        name = "integer array";
        h5xx::create_dataset(file, name, array);
        h5xx::write_dataset(file, name, array);

        // --- create a slice object (aka hyperslab) to specify the location in the dataset to be overwritten
        std::vector<int> offset; int offset_raw[2] = {4,4}; offset.assign(offset_raw, offset_raw + 2);
        std::vector<int> count;  int count_raw[2] = {2,2}; count.assign(count_raw, count_raw + 2);
        h5xx::slice slice(offset, count);
    }
}
void read_int_data(std::string const& filename)
{
    h5xx::file file(filename, h5xx::file::in);
    std::string name = "integer array";

    // read and print the full dataset
    {
        array_2d_t array;
        // --- read the complete dataset into array, the array is resized and overwritten internally
        h5xx::read_dataset(file, name, array);
        printf("original integer array read from file, negative number patch was written using a slice\n");
        print_array(array);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::string filename = argv[0];
    filename.append(".h5");

    // --- do a few demos/tests using integers
    {
        array_2d_t array(boost::extents[NJ][NI]);
        {
            const int nelem = NI*NJ;
            int data[nelem];
            for (int i = 0; i < nelem; i++)
                data[i] = i;
            array.assign(data, data + nelem);
        }

        write_int_data(filename, array);

        read_int_data(filename);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm using the h5xx — a template-based C++ wrapper for the HDF5 library [link](https://github.com/h5md/h5xx) and boost library.
The datasets are stored in particles/lipids/box/positions path. The dataset name value holds the frames.

Comment: What object from the h5 file are you reading? Having "the shape" is not nearly enough. What data are the frames? Lipids? Positions? Edges? By the way HDFView is not cooperative on my machine: https://i.imgur.com/qbMhln3.png

Comment: @sehe I added the path of the dataset in the question. It is stored under /particles/lipids/box/positions/value.

Comment: And the attribute name? type?

Comment: @sehe the name of the dataset is called **value**

Comment: That's the name of the dataset, but it doesn't appear to ba an array. What is the type in the file? It's pretty hard /tedious to reverse engineer this. If you can't describe what the file contains, it's hard to tell how to read it.

Comment: It is a numpy array. If you look into this question *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69242841/how-to-create-attributes-to-the-groups-and-access-them-in-hdf5-file-system* the created dataset name **value**. In addition to that using this **h5ls -r xaa.h5** in command line you can see all the groups, datasets and attributes.

Comment: Cool. That tool is not described on the HDF5 site. It would have saved me a ton of time. Also, if you can exactly specify what the file contains/how it is made that is likely _essential_ information when asking about reading it :) We're getting somewhere now

Comment: the file contains two main groups h5md and particles. The data I want to read is contained in **/particles/lipids/box/positions/value Dataset {75/Inf, 11214, 3}** . Value has a dataset of shape (75,11214,3). I want to access this data. Using this command **h5ls -d xaa.h5/particles/lipids/box/positions/value | less** you can actually see the data. I hope it makes clear!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238471/discussion-between-sehe-and-rohit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0. `argv[0]` is not what you want (arguments start at 1, 0 is the program name). Consider bounds checking as well:

   ```
   std::vector<std::string> const args(argv, argv + argc);
   std::string const              filename = args.at(1) + ".h5";
   ```
1. the initialization can be done directly, without a temporary array (what is multi_array for, otherwise?)

   ```
   for (size_t i = 0; i < array.num_elements(); i++)
       array.data()[i] = i;
   ```
2. Or indeed, make it an algorithm:

   ```
    std::iota(array.data(), array.data() + array.num_elements(), 0);
   ```
3. same with vectors:

   ```
   std::vector<int> offset; int offset_raw[2] = {4,4}; offset.assign(offset_raw, offset_raw + 2);
   std::vector<int> count;  int count_raw[2] = {2,2}; count.assign(count_raw, count_raw + 2);
   ```

   besides being a formatting mess can be simply

   ```
   std::vector offset{4,4}, count{2,2};
   h5xx::slice slice(offset, count);
   ```

### On To The Real Question

The code has no relevance to the file. At all. I created some debug/tracing code to dump the file contents:

```
void dump(h5xx::group const& g, std::string indent = "") {
    auto dd = g.datasets();
    auto gg = g.groups();

    for (auto it = dd.begin(); it != dd.end(); ++it) {
        std::cout << indent << " ds:" << it.get_name() << "\n";
    }

    for (auto it = gg.begin(); it != gg.end(); ++it) {
        dump(*it, indent + "/" + it.get_name());
    }
}

int main()
{
    h5xx::file xaa("xaa.h5", h5xx::file::mode::in);

    dump(xaa);
}
```

Prints

```
/particles/lipids/box/edges ds:box_size
/particles/lipids/box/edges ds:step
/particles/lipids/box/edges ds:time
/particles/lipids/box/edges ds:value
/particles/lipids/box/positions ds:step
/particles/lipids/box/positions ds:time
/particles/lipids/box/positions ds:value
```

Now we can drill down to the dataset. Let's see whether we can figure out the correct type. It certainly is NOT `array_2d_t`:

```
h5xx::dataset ds(xaa, "particles/lipids/box/positions/value");

array_2d_t a;
h5xx::datatype detect(a);
std::cout << "type:   " << std::hex << ds.get_type() << std::dec << "\n";
std::cout << "detect: " << std::hex << detect.get_type_id() << std::dec << "\n";
```

Prints

```
type:   30000000000013b
detect: 30000000000000c
```

That's a type mismatch. I guess I'll have to learn to read that gibberish as well...

Let's add some diagnostics:

```
void diag_type(hid_t type)
{
    std::cout << " Class     " << ::H5Tget_class(type)       << std::endl;
    std::cout << " Size      " << ::H5Tget_size(type)        << std::endl;
    std::cout << " Sign      " << ::H5Tget_sign(type)        << std::endl;
    std::cout << " Order     " << ::H5Tget_order(type)       << std::endl;
    std::cout << " Precision " << ::H5Tget_precision(type)   << std::endl;
    std::cout << " NDims     " << ::H5Tget_array_ndims(type) << std::endl;
    std::cout << " NMembers  " << ::H5Tget_nmembers(type)    << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    h5xx::file xaa("xaa.h5", h5xx::file::mode::in);
    // dump(xaa);

    {
        h5xx::group g(xaa, "particles/lipids/box/positions");
        h5xx::dataset ds(g, "value");
        std::cout << "dataset:   " << std::hex << ds.get_type() << std::dec << std::endl;
        diag_type(ds.get_type());
    }

    {
        array_2d_t     a(boost::extents[NJ][NI]);
        h5xx::datatype detect(a);
        std::cout << "detect: " << std::hex << detect.get_type_id() << std::dec << std::endl;
        diag_type(detect.get_type_id());
    }
}
```

Prints

```
dataset:   30000000000013b
 Class     1
 Size      4
 Sign      -1
 Order     0
 Precision 32
 NDims     -1
 NMembers  -1
detect: 30000000000000c
 Class     0
 Size      4
 Sign      1
 Order     0
 Precision 32
 NDims     -1
 NMembers  -1
```

At least we know that `HST_FLOAT` (class 1) is required. Let's modify `array_2d_t`:

```
using array_2d_t = boost::multi_array<float, 2>;
array_2d_t a(boost::extents[11214][3]);
```

This at least makes the data appear similarly. Let's ... naively try to read:

```
h5xx::read_dataset(ds, a);
```

Oops, that predictably throws

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'h5xx::error'
  what():  /home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/deps/h5xx/h5xx/dataset/boost_multi_array.hpp:176:read_dataset(): dataset "/particles/lipi
ds/box/positions/value" and target array have mismatching dimensions
```

No worries, we can guess:

```
using array_3d_t = boost::multi_array<float, 3>;
array_3d_t     a(boost::extents[10][11214][3]);
h5xx::read_dataset(ds, a);
```

At least this **does** work. Adapting the print function:

```
template <typename T> void print_array(T const& array) {
    for (auto const& row : array) {
        for (auto v : row) printf("%5f ", v);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Now we can print the first frame:

```
h5xx::read_dataset(ds, a);
print_array(*a.begin()); // print the first frame
```

This prints:

```
80.480003 35.360001 4.250000
37.450001 3.920000 3.960000
18.530001 -9.690000 4.680000
55.389999 74.339996 4.600000
22.110001 68.709999 3.850000
-4.130000 24.040001 3.730000
40.160000 6.390000 4.730000
-5.400000 35.730000 4.850000
36.669998 22.450001 4.080000
-3.680000 -10.660000 4.180000
(...)
```

That checks out with `h5ls -r -d xaa.h5/particles/lipids/box/positions/value`:

```
particles/lipids/box/positions/value Dataset {75/Inf, 11214, 3}
    Data:
        (0,0,0) 80.48, 35.36, 4.25, 37.45, 3.92, 3.96, 18.53, -9.69, 4.68,
        (0,3,0) 55.39, 74.34, 4.6, 22.11, 68.71, 3.85, -4.13, 24.04, 3.73,
        (0,6,0) 40.16, 6.39, 4.73, -5.4, 35.73, 4.85, 36.67, 22.45, 4.08, -3.68,
        (0,9,1) -10.66, 4.18, 35.95, 36.43, 5.15, 57.17, 3.88, 5.08, -23.64,
        (0,12,1) 50.44, 4.32, 6.78, 8.24, 4.36, 21.34, 50.63, 5.21, 16.29,
        (0,15,1) -1.34, 5.28, 22.26, 71.25, 5.4, 19.76, 10.38, 5.34, 78.62,
        (0,18,1) 11.13, 5.69, 22.14, 59.7, 4.92, 15.65, 47.28, 5.22, 82.41,
        (0,21,1) 2.09, 5.24, 16.87, -11.68, 5.35, 15.54, -0.63, 5.2, 81.25,
(...)
```

### The Home Stretch: Adding The Slice

```
array_2d_t read_frame(int frame_no) {
    h5xx::file xaa("xaa.h5", h5xx::file::mode::in);

    h5xx::group   g(xaa, "particles/lipids/box/positions");
    h5xx::dataset ds(g, "value");

    array_2d_t a(boost::extents[11214][3]);

    std::vector offsets{frame_no, 0, 0}, counts{1, 11214, 3};
    h5xx::slice slice(offsets, counts);

    h5xx::read_dataset(ds, a, slice);
    return a;
}
```

There you have it. Now we can print any frame:

```
print_array(read_frame(0));
```

Printing the same as before. Let's try the last frame:

```
print_array(read_frame(9));
```

Prints

```
79.040001 36.349998 3.990000
37.250000 3.470000 4.140000
18.600000 -9.270000 4.900000
55.669998 75.070000 5.370000
21.920000 67.709999 3.790000
-4.670000 24.770000 3.690000
40.000000 6.060000 5.240000
-5.340000 36.320000 5.410000
36.369999 22.490000 4.130000
-3.520000 -10.430000 4.280000
(...)
```

Checking again with `h5ls -r -d xaa.h5/particles/lipids/box/positions/value |& grep '(9' | head` confirms:

```
(9,0,0) 79.04, 36.35, 3.99, 37.25, 3.47, 4.14, 18.6, -9.27, 4.9, 55.67,
(9,3,1) 75.07, 5.37, 21.92, 67.71, 3.79, -4.67, 24.77, 3.69, 40, 6.06,
(9,6,2) 5.24, -5.34, 36.32, 5.41, 36.37, 22.49, 4.13, -3.52, -10.43,
(9,9,2) 4.28, 35.8, 36.43, 4.99, 56.6, 4.09, 5.04, -23.37, 49.42, 3.81,
(9,13,0) 6.31, 8.83, 4.56, 22.01, 50.38, 5.43, 16.3, -2.92, 5.4, 22.02,
(9,16,1) 70.09, 5.36, 20.23, 11.12, 5.66, 78.48, 11.34, 6.09, 20.26,
(9,19,1) 61.45, 5.35, 14.25, 48.32, 5.35, 79.95, 1.71, 5.38, 17.56,
(9,22,1) -11.61, 5.39, 15.64, -0.19, 5.06, 80.43, 71.77, 5.29, 75.54,
(9,25,1) 35.14, 5.26, 22.45, 56.86, 5.56, 16.47, 52.97, 6.16, 20.62,
(9,28,1) 65.12, 5.26, 19.68, 71.2, 5.52, 23.39, 49.84, 5.28, 22.7,
```

### Full Listing

```
#include <boost/multi_array.hpp>
#include <h5xx/h5xx.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using array_2d_t = boost::multi_array<float, 2>;

template <typename T> void print_array(T const& array)
{
    for (auto const& row : array) { for (auto v : row)
            printf("%5f ", v);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void dump(h5xx::group const& g, std::string indent = "") {
    auto dd = g.datasets();
    auto gg = g.groups();

    for (auto it = dd.begin(); it != dd.end(); ++it) {
        std::cout << indent << " ds:" << it.get_name() << std::endl;
    }

    for (auto it = gg.begin(); it != gg.end(); ++it) {
        dump(*it, indent + "/" + it.get_name());
    }
}

array_2d_t read_frame(int frame_no) {
    h5xx::file xaa("xaa.h5", h5xx::file::mode::in);

    h5xx::group   g(xaa, "particles/lipids/box/positions");
    h5xx::dataset ds(g, "value");

    array_2d_t arr(boost::extents[11214][3]);

    std::vector offsets{frame_no, 0, 0}, counts{1, 11214, 3};
    h5xx::slice slice(offsets, counts);

    h5xx::read_dataset(ds, arr, slice);
    return arr;
}

int main()
{
    print_array(read_frame(9));
}
```