# The fastest way to save large volumes in C++ using boost::asio

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2019, boost-asio

I'm looking for a way save large 3-dimensional matrices (>1GB) as quickly as possible in C++. I have a feeling that I should look into boost:asio and do asynchronous and multi-threading.

On the hardware side, I have a PCIe gen 3 RAID card with 4 M.2 NVMe drives. Using a the [CrystalDiskMark benchmark](https://crystalmark.info/en/software/crystaldiskmark/), I reached a writing speed of 14GB/s. Therefore, the goal is to get as close as possible to this speed.

After some testing, I arrived at the following code, which allows me to achieve an average speed of 8GB/s. There is no multi-threading, and the handling of asynchronous operations is very basic:

```
bool save_boostAsio_append(char* i_data, char* i_filePath, int64_t i_totalSize) {
    boost::asio::io_context ioContext;
    boost::asio::windows::random_access_handle handle(ioContext);

    // File opening with read/write access
    handle.assign(::CreateFileA(i_filePath, GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, nullptr, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED | FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING, nullptr));

    if (!handle.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open file." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Create a mutable buffer for the data
    auto buffer = boost::asio::buffer(i_data, i_totalSize);

    // Go to end of the file GetFileSize.
    DWORD file_size_high;
    DWORD file_size_low = ::GetFileSize(handle.native_handle(), &file_size_high);

    // Asynchronous async_write that append at the end of the file
    handle.async_write_some_at(file_size_low, buffer, handle_write);

    // io_context execution
    ioContext.run();
    handle.close();
    return 0;
}
```

**Question 1:** Is my simple asynchronous handling sufficient, or can it be improved ?

**Question 2:** How to manage multi-threading with boost to write to the same file ?

**Bonus question:** How about the [multiqueue](https://infohub.delltechnologies.com/l/nvme-nvme-tcp-and-dell-smartfabric-storage-software-overview-ip-san-solution-primer-1/nvme-multiqueue-interface) ?

I'm using Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: Actually your code is not asynchronous. It does call `async_write_some_at`, but then immediately calls `ioContext.run` which blocks until all outstanding operations (in your case the `async_write_some_at` are finished. Therefore, `save_boostAsio_append` is a synchronous call.

Comment: Asio and asynchronous programming models in general are not so much about maximising throughput, but about running many tasks concurrently. Did you also measure the writing speed using plain standard file streams?

Comment: OK so I completly misunderstanding the ioContext.run command. I suppose I need to chop my buffer into chunks and use async_write_some_at smartly in a loop to make it asynchronous, and finally end my code with ioContext.run. Is that right ?

Comment: To answer the other question and add some context, I first used an fwrite function in MATLAB (the code I wrote earlier is an extract of a .mex function). Then I tried an fwrite function in C++ (using .mex). In both case, I achieve a 3.5 GB/s, far away from the 14GB/s given by the CrystalDiskMark benchmark.

Comment: It is possible that the benchmark from CrystalDiskMark is just too optimistic. Supposing that the benchmark just writes a few megabytes and then deletes in a loop. The measured speed will be much higher than reality because there is no need for the OS to actually flush to disk. And even if it does, the disk may well be faster with medium size files than with huge ones. On SSD, the slowest process is deleting (purging) sectors so that they are 0xFF again and can be written anew. That purge is done asynchronously by the OS.

Comment: I don't know about the RAID speed limitation on this type of card I use, but each NVMe (Firecuda 530 2To) is supposed to have a really good writing speed using cache (7GB/s) (https://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/seagate-firecuda-530-m2-nvme-ssd-review/2). Even without cache, I should reach the 4GB/s.
In my case, it's only PCIe gen 3, so we can expect to reach the 4 PCIe lanes speed limit (1GB/s per lane, so 4GB/s). 
So I'm still not satisfy with my 8GB/s bad implemented solution, I'm pretty sure I can go at least to 10GB/s.

Comment: Consider something specialized like e.g. hdf5 (example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69689617/how-to-read-chunk-of-the-data-from-a-hdf5-file-in-c/69693209#69693209)